# Check if pandas row is unique, when order is not considered

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, drop-duplicates

I wondered if there is a way to check and then drop certain rows which are not unique?

My data frame looks something like this:

```
    ID1 ID2 weight  
 0  2   4   0.5
 1  3   7   0.8 
 2  4   2   0.5 
 3  7   3   0.8
 4  8   2   0.5
 5  3   8   0.5
```

EDIT: I added a couple more rows to show that other unique rows that may have the same weight should be kept.

I think that when I use pandas `drop_duplicates(subset=['ID1', 'ID2','weight'], keep=False)` it considers each row individually but not recognise that rows 0 and 2 and 1 and 4 are in fact the same values?

Comment: The values in ID1 and ID2 are different, are you saying that the values in ID1 and ID2 are swappable?

Comment: you just set your subset correctly `drop_duplicates(subset=['weight'])`

Comment: @TYZ yes so the IDs may be different but the pair is the same if that makes sense? It does not matter if  2,4 is = 0.5 or 4,2 is = 0.5?

Comment: @YOLO thank you for your suggestion - would this mean that other values that are also of weight 0.5 but have IDs 9,8, for example, would be dropped?

Comment: @YOLO It will work for this particular data, but not gonna work in general if there's a row like `3, 4, 0.5`.

Comment: @TYZ yes thank you this is what I meant!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort the dataframe along `axis=1` then use `np.unique` with optional param `return_index=True` to get the indices of unique elements:

```
sub = ['ID1', 'ID2', 'weight']

idx = np.unique(np.sort(df[sub], 1), axis=0, return_index=True)[1]
df1 = df.iloc[sorted(idx)]
```

Alternative approach suggested by @anky:

```
df1 = df[~pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[sub], 1), index=df.index).duplicated()]
```

---

```
print(df1)

   ID1  ID2  weight
0    2    4     0.5
1    3    7     0.8
4    8    2     0.5
5    3    8     0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

This works, but it's kind of hacky. Create sets from columns that should be pairs and convert to tuples to get hashable types

```
df['new'] = df[['ID1','ID2']].apply(lambda x: tuple(set(x)), axis=1)
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['new','weight'], keep=False)
```

Out:

```
   ID1  ID2  weight     new
4    8    2     0.5  (8, 2)
5    3    8     0.5  (8, 3)
```