# Removing all non-unique rows from a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Sorry, this is my second post - please let me know if something doesn't make sense!

I'm trying to remove all rows that have any duplicates. I've tried the `keep = False` parameter for `drop_duplicates()`, and its just not doing the right thing.

lets say my dataframe looks something like this

```
|ORDER ID | ITEM CODE |
123         XXX    
123         YYY
123         YYY
456         XXX
456         XXX
456         XXX
789         XXX
000         YYY
```

I want it to look like this:

```
|ORDER ID | ITEM CODE |
123         XXX    
789         XXX
000         YYY
```

Comment: You want to get all unique values. Does this help? https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html

Comment: dont think that works on a dataframe

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='ORDER ID')
```

Comment: this keeps ONE of the duplicate values, I need anything that isnt a unique row to be dropped

Comment: Ok, so your example of how you want your DF to look like is wrong, since it does not match what you are requesting, right?

Comment: no, please look again, the only rows left are unique values

Comment: "123" is not unique. It occurs 3 times in your DF.

Comment: the subset would be on both the columns

Answer (score 1):

let's define your sample DataFrame,

```
data = {"ORDER ID":[123, 123, 123, 456, 456, 456, 789, 000], "ITEM CODE":['XXX', 'YYY', 'YYY', 'XXX', 'XXX', 'XXX', 'XXX', 'YYY']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

 ORDER ID ITEM CODE
  123       XXX
  123       YYY
  123       YYY
  456       XXX
  456       XXX
  456       XXX
  789       XXX
  000       YYY
```

You can remove duplicates based on desired columns or all columns, subset parameter can be a list of column names.

```
new_df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='ORDER ID')

 ORDER ID ITEM CODE
  123       XXX
  456       XXX
  789       XXX
  000       YYY
```

Answer (score 0):

So I suggest that you use a loop to iterate through every row, then whilst iterating through each line use an if statement to compare the current row to the last, if it is exclude, if it isn't return the row.

Comment: the dataset is too large to iterate through each row and the duplicates arent necessarily bunched together, unless you have a piece of code i could try

Comment: Oh so you want to just remove them entirely? Try to add duplicates to a case list that of which you want removed, then it will update the list, also if input is too large you can always section the first couple of lines in the list then append to a new file.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to compile the answer from two other answers:

1. We shall find the lines to drop. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64105947/2681662
2. We use that dataframe to drop it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44706892/2681662

### Find lines to drop:

```
import pandas as pd

lst = [
    [123, "XXX"],
    [123, "YYY"],
    [123, "YYY"],
    [456, "XXX"],
    [456, "XXX"],
    [456, "XXX"],
    [789, "XXX"],
    [000, "YYY"],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=["ORDER ID", "ITEM CODE"])

to_drop = df[pd.DataFrame(df.sort_values(by=["ORDER ID", "ITEM CODE"]), index=df.index).duplicated()]
```

### Drop all lines according to `to_drop`

So the whole code would look like:

```
import pandas as pd

lst = [
    [123, "XXX"],
    [123, "YYY"],
    [123, "YYY"],
    [456, "XXX"],
    [456, "XXX"],
    [456, "XXX"],
    [789, "XXX"],
    [000, "YYY"],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=["ORDER ID", "ITEM CODE"])

to_drop = df[pd.DataFrame(df.sort_values(by=["ORDER ID", "ITEM CODE"]), index=df.index).duplicated()]

print(pd.merge(df,to_drop, indicator=True, how='outer')
         .query('_merge=="left_only"')
         .drop('_merge', axis=1))
```

Comment: this looks like it would work! ill let you know if it does - thanks so much!

Comment: hey so i run into an error that says i cannot reindex from a duplicated axis. Also I should let you know that there are other columns in my table so i ran the duplicated() with a subset parameter