# Getting ONLY unique rows from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to remove all rows that have any duplicates. I ONLY want the unique rows. I've tried the `keep = False` parameter for `drop_duplicates()` with `subset = [ORDER ID, ITEM CODE] , and its just not doing the right thing.

lets say my dataframe looks something like this

```
|ORDER ID | ITEM CODE |
123         XXX    
123         YYY
123         YYY
456         XXX
456         XXX
456         XXX
789         XXX
000         YYY
```

I want it to look like this:

```
|ORDER ID | ITEM CODE |
123         XXX    
789         XXX
000         YYY
```

As you can see the subset would be both the order ID and Item code columns and we would lose rows 2-6 ideally. (The actual dataset has a lot more columns.)

Comment: _it's just not doing the right thing_. Okay, but what is it doing?

Comment: Do you get the data from a database? You could use `SELECT DISTINCT` as statement in your database query than.

Comment: By the way, `(123, XXX)` and `(123, YYY)` are unique rows, so your expected output seems incorrect. And where did `456` order go?

Comment: unfortunately, the data is originally from a DB but this file I'm working on has been heavily manipulated so the fix would have to be in python

Comment: 123,YYY is not unique since you can see it has a duplicate so it would not be required in the expected output

Comment: works absolutely fine for me. What exactly is your `.drop_duplicates()` line? What version of pandas you on?

Comment: Why do you ask [the same question as you posted yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69858242/removing-all-non-unique-rows-from-a-dataframe)?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your issue is. Works fine.

```
import pandas as pd


data = [[123,         'XXX', 11],    
[123,         'YYY', 22],
[123,         'YYY', 33],
[456,         'XXX', 44],
[456,         'XXX', 55],
[456,         'XXX', 66],
[789,         'XXX',77],
[000,         'YYY',88]]

columns = ['ORDER ID','ITEM CODE','extra column']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

df = df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['ORDER ID','ITEM CODE'], keep=False)
```

**Output:**

Before

```
print(df)
   ORDER ID ITEM CODE  extra column
0       123       XXX            11
1       123       YYY            22
2       123       YYY            33
3       456       XXX            44
4       456       XXX            55
5       456       XXX            66
6       789       XXX            77
7         0       YYY            88
```

After

```
print(df)
   ORDER ID ITEM CODE  extra column
0       123       XXX            11
6       789       XXX            77
7         0       YYY            88
```

Comment: what version of pandas should i be on?

Comment: that's so weird that it doesnt workfor me

Comment: I'm on  `'1.3.3'`. Try to upgrade `pip install pandas --upgrade`

Comment: are you absolutely sure the the values are duplicates? Sometimes there could be white space you're not aware of. For example `'XXX'` and `'XXX '`

Comment: omg it worked - thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your subset to include `ORDER ID` only:

```py
df.drop_duplicated(subset=['ORDER ID'])
```

Comment: this wouldnt work because it would leave me with the first duplicated value (keep=First) is default.

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that you are simply not setting the dataframe properly. You might be doing

```
df.drop_duplicates()
```

But this would fail to overwrite your previous values. Rather you should be doing

```
df = df.drop_duplicates()
```

If you can't get drop_duplicates to work, you can use numpy.unique as a workaround.

```
df['ORDER_ID'] = np.unique(df['ORDER_ID'])
df['ITEM_CODE'] = np.unique(df['ITEM_CODE'])
```